# Perform assignment only if right side is not nil

Tags: swift

Is there a possibility to only perform an assignment (e.g. to a non-optional property) if the right hand side is not nil? I am looking for a one-line form for:

```
if let unwrapped = funcThatReturnsOptional() {
    object.nonOptionalProperty = unwrapped
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, actually there is a way to achieve exactly this by introducing a new operator `?=`:

```
infix operator ?= : AssignmentPrecedence
func ?= <T: Any> (left: inout T, right: T?) {
    if let right = right {
        left = right
    }
}
```

By using `?=` defined as above you can actually assign an optional to a non-optional if the optional has a value inside.

Comment: Yes, but note that passing a variable as an inout expression in `myVar ?= nil` to the operator will call the property observers willSet/didSet, and both get/set in the case of a computed property, even if you don't assign a new value inside the operator.

Comment: @MartinR well you are correct, but at least it shortens the expression.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore. Fix your answer please

Comment: @Gargo fixed now

Comment: @Ch1llb4y what about to cut `if let right = right {` to just `if let right {` ?

Answer (score 8):

A single expression with the same effect as your code is

```
funcThatReturnsOptional().map { object.nonOptionalProperty = $0 }
```

but your code is definitely better readable.

Here the `map()` method of `Optional` is used and the closure is
executed only if the function does not return `nil`.

Comment: well okay this is actually one line but it looks really horrible :D thought there is some better readable solution (maybe something with `??` operator)

Comment: @Ch1llb4y: I don't know such a solution. You could define a custom assignment operator. The problem is that inout parameters trigger the property setter even if you don't assign a new value in the operator function.

Comment: I would not expect that solution to be accepted, because it is way worse than the standard `if` condition way. Even if the OP's goal is fulfilled, it is pretty obvious that the goal here was to make it more readable and minimalistic with a binary operator. And hey, you can always write that `if` condition on the one line as well then.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář: As I said: *"... but your code is definitely better readable."* – Using a binary operator for that purpose cannot be done without side effects, as I mentioned below.

Comment: @MartinR I do not question that, I'm surprised about the A being accepted. Important is that it is not possible with a build-in operator and a custom one would have some side effects.

Answer (score 5):

There are various ways that aren't too unwieldy

Using ?? :

```
object.nonOptionalProperty = funcThatReturnsOptional() ?? object.nonOptionalProperty
```

Using a function :

```
func setNotNil<T>(inout variable:T, _ value:T?)
{ if value != nil { variable = value! } }

setNotNil(&object.nonOptionalProperty, funcThatReturnsOptional())
```

Using an operator :

```
infix operator <-?? { associativity right precedence 90 assignment }
func <-??<T>(inout variable:T, value:T?)
{ if value != nil { variable = value! } }

object.nonOptionalProperty <-?? funcThatReturnsOptional()
```

Using an extension :

```
extension Equatable
{ mutating func setNotNil(value:Self?) { if value != nil { self = value! } } }

object.nonOptionalProperty.setNotNil(funcThatReturnsOptional())
```

Comment: Well all of them trigger the setter of the `nonOptionalProperty`, as the old value is being re-assigned.

Comment: I changed the function implementation but if your concern with that is assignment to chain optionals, please have a look at my answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838661/crash-on-unwrapping-nil-optional/34867082#34867082

Comment: @AlainT. check your answer please - it doesn't work anymore without of additional fixes

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Sajjon could be improved by using an `if let` to avoid reflection.

```
precedencegroup OptionalAssignment { associativity: right }

infix operator ?= : OptionalAssignment

public func ?= <T>(variable: inout T, value: T?) {
    if let value = value {
        variable = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `assignment: true` so it can be used with `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the solution provided by @ch1llb4y nor by @tyler-sheaffer works since generics loses information about optional values. But this can be fixed using the `unwrap` method below.

```
precedencegroup OptionalAssignment {
    associativity: right
}

infix operator ?= : OptionalAssignment

public func ?= <T>(variable: inout T, value: T?) {
    if let unwrapped = unwrap(any: value) ?? nil {
        variable = unwrapped
    }
}

public func unwrap<T: Any>(any: T) -> T? {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    guard mirror.displayStyle == .optional else { return any }
    guard let child = mirror.children.first else { return nil }
    return unwrap(any: child.value) as? T
}
```

I have not yet come up with a solution for not having to write `?? nil` in `unwrap(any: value) ?? nil` though.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it with a closure like this:

```
let unwrapped = { funcThatReturnsOptional() ?? object.nonOptionalProperty }()
```

That way you can also use it guard statements in case you are dealing with multiple optional properties:

```
guard let unwrapped = { funcThatReturnsOptional() ?? object.OptionalProperty }() else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Swift is all about protocols, and POP, a solution involving protocols was bound to happen.

Here's a kinky protocol that allows you to assign an optional value to a non-optional property:

```swift
protocol OptionalShortcut { }

extension OptionalShortcut {
    subscript<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Self,T>) -> T? {
        get { self[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { if let newValue = newValue { self[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue } }
    }
}
```

Just have your class/struct/enum/actor conform to the above protocol, and you can write the assignment like this:

```swift
object[\.nonOptionalProperty] = funcThatReturnsOptional()
```

I personally don't like the subscript and key path syntax (square brackets are ugly unless they involve collections), but thought to give the solution, for completeness.