# Crash on unwrapping nil optional

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics, option-type

I made a new operator which associate a value to a target only if the value is not nil, otherwise does nothing.
Basically it's a synthetic sugar for `if let foo = foo { faa = foo }`:

```
infix operator =? {}
func =?<T>(inout lhs: T, rhs: T?) {
    if let rhs = rhs {
        lhs = rhs
    }
}
func =?<T>(inout lhs: T?, rhs: T?) {
    if let rhs = rhs {
        lhs = rhs
    }
}
```

That way I can save some typing:

```
// instead this:
if let x = maybeX {
    z = x
}

// I can do this:
z =? x
```

My issue is that when I get to the line of execution (`z =? x`) I crash even before entering the implementation func with the exception:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It appears Swift tries to force unwrap `x` even when the implementation accepts `T?`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not crashing here. What about the nil coalescing operator? It exists, it works, and it is more readable.

Comment: Is it possible you have another implementation of this operator?

Comment: @RMenke doing `z = x ?? z` forces me to set a value to `z`... (unless `z = z` does nothing?)

Comment: I have 2 implementations as you can see in the question, for the case where `lhs` is optional or not, but both have `rhs` as `T?`...

Comment: `z = x ?? z` is what I do. Still very weird that I can't get it to crash. Are your trying this a playground with no other code around? And with which types (not that that should matter, but maybe a bug...)?

Comment: To the down voter: please give feedback to the OP rather than a drive-by down vote, I think this is a legitimate question (possibly the title could be less general).

Comment: How are `z` and `x` defined? A short *self-contained* example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be my mistake... I was using `foo.z = ...` where `foo` was a nil `UIImageView!`... damm views from nib...

I would happily change my implementation with a nil coalescing operator following @RMenke suggestion but as far as I know this will cause a redundant action of setting z to z when x is nil...
e.g.:

```
var z = someFoo()
var x: Int? = nil
z = x ?? z
// will this re-write z's reference to z again or simply do nothing?
```

@MartinR made an important comment:

> if an operator (or function) takes an inout-parameter, then the property setter will be called on return even if you don't assign a new value inside the operator

Trying to solve the issue, I made the following extension as a cleaner version of the `_ = foo.map...` approach:

```
extension Optional {
    public func use<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows {
        _ = try self.map(f)
    }
}

//then:
x.use{ z = $0 }
```

It's probably better since it does not call z's setter when x is nil, but is it the cleanest/clearest way?

Comment: A similar question was discussed here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698272/perform-assignment-only-if-right-side-is-not-nil. Note that if an operator (or function) takes an inout-parameter, then the property setter will be called on return even if you don't assign a new value inside the operator (which may or may not be a problem for you).

Comment: Sure, that would be a wrapper for flatMap which ignores the return value. You can simplify it slightly to `_ = try self.map(f)`.

Comment: Is `self.` needed here, can't it be simplified even to `_ = try map(f)`?

Comment: I could, I left it for readability, doing simply `map..` feels a bit out of context... mapping what? doesn't feel so clear that it's on self... But you are right it's not needed in the chars-slicing approach....

Answer (score -1):

Your operator works but you should have used chained optionals: foo?.z = ...

However, this will give you another kind of error when foo is nil which you can fix by adding

```
func =?<T>(lhs: T??, rhs: T?) -> ()
{}
```

This "do-nothing" version of the operator absorbs the unmutable parameter version that you get when passing an optional chain that has a nil before the last member.

Comment: So, how will this work with optional chaining? My experiments show that this overload is going to be always used, thus assignment to never happen. Looks like a terrible advice, people might wonder why their assignment never work.  I was as well trying to create ?= operator (academical interest), but this optional chaining unmutable parameter error really breaks the whole idea.