# Swift: Is there a more succinct way to write the "if let" block below?

Tags: swift, if-statement, option-type

```
   if let phone = participant.phone {
                participantObject["phone"] = phone
            } else { print("Did not add phone") }
```

I need to unwrap an "String?" and only make the assignment if the optional is not nil

Comment: You could use the `map()` method of `Optional` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698272/perform-assignment-only-if-right-side-is-not-nil for a similar question). But that does not make it better legible.

Comment: you can try `participantObject["phone"] = participant.phone ?? participantObject["phone"]` which will use `participant.phone` if it is not nil, otherwise assign self to self

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since assigning a `nil` value to a Swift dictionary removes the key you can easily use this syntax:

```
participantObject["phone"] = participant.phone
```

unless you want to preserve an existing value. Then there is no better syntax than yours.

---

However if you want to assign an alternative value if `phone` is `nil`, use the `nil coalescing` operator.

```
participantObject["phone"] = participant.phone ?? "n/a"
```

Comment: Although it's useful to know about the `??` operator, I'd definitely advise against using it in this way. It's way easier to use `if let phone = participantObject["phone"]` somewhere else in the program, than to have to test if that value is equal to `"n/a"`.

Comment: The `??` operator would be very useful if you want to show the phone number on screen, though: you could use something like `phoneLabel.text = participantObject["phone"] ?? "n/a"`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use

```
participatnObject["phone"] = participant.phone
```

because this code will simply only set the value for the key `"phone"` if `participant.phone` isn't `nil`. The only difference is that this code will remove a previous value for the `"phone"` key, if it was there, which doesn't happen with your code.

If you also need to print a message if no assignment was done, then your code is quite optimal. This is slightly shorter though:

```
participatnObject["phone"] = participant.phone
if participant.phone == nil { print("Did not add phone") }
```