# Swift short hand for assignment of Optional values

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm wondering if there's a 'short hand' form of assigning Optional values to non-optional values without doing if nil check.

For example if I've got an Optional closure:

```
var onTap: (() -> Void)?
```

I can later on call this via

```
 onTap?()
```

The `?` let's me skip the nil check and force unwrap.

But I'm curious if something exists for values that are not clousre. For example

```
var oldTransform: CGAffineTransform?
var someTransform: CGAffineTransform //non optional
```

and later on, I decide to assign `oldTransform` to `someTransform` I have to

```
if (oldTransform != nil) {
  someTransform = oldTransform!
}
```

Is there a pattern that's less verbose to do the above (kinda of like the `?`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform assignment only if right side is not nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698272/perform-assignment-only-if-right-side-is-not-nil)

Comment: @DávidPásztor - possibly, but the accepted answer to that doesn't use `??` it suggests `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. You could use if let as below:

```
if let unwrappedOldTransForm = oldTransform {
    someTransform = unwrappedOldTransForm
}
```

When you check with if let, it will unwrap the value for you and check if it can set the value of oldTransform to unwrappedOldTransForm. If the value is nil you will be able to handle the error by adding an else condition as below:

```
if let unwrappedOldTransForm = oldTransform {
    someTransform = unwrappedOldTransForm
} else {
    // handle if oldTransform is nil
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this but it's not much better. Looking for something short like onTap?() . If not, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a function, as you know, "calling" a nil function (like `onTap?()`) has no effect - but for an assignment to a non-optional type you need to supply a definite non-optional value. For that you can use the nil-coalescing operator `??` like so:

```
var optionalString: String?
// ... maybe set optionalString ...

var realString: String = optionalString ?? "<some default value>"
```

In your example, it would be

```
someTransform = oldTransform ?? CGAffineTransform(...) // some default - say Identity
```

or even, as commentator @user28434 suggests

```
someTransform = oldTransform ?? someTransform // assuming someTransform already initialised
```

which will only change someTranform if oldTransform isn't nil.

In each case, the left hand operand of `??` will be assigned if is non-nil, otherwise the right hand side operand will be assigned.

Comment: `// some default - say Identity` or just `someTransform`

Comment: @user28434 - indeed, if it had already been initialised (it wasn't in his example, just declared).

Comment: Swift code won't compile if there's non-initialised non-optional, non-void variable, so we may assume it is initialised.

Comment: @user28434 - That assignation may have *been* the initialisation. There is no need to initialise at point of declaration.

Comment: indeed, then example from question has to have `else` part.