# Nil-Coalescing Operator without changing value

Tags: swift, option-type, swift4

Nil-Coalescing Operators are one of my favorite things about Swift. Since becoming quite familiar with Swift, I've run into a few different special cases. One is where I want to assign an `Optional` value to a variable if it exists, otherwise, do nothing. I currently see two ways of doing this:

```
var a : String?
var b : String?

// Possibly assign a non-nil value to a and/or b

/* First Way */
a = b ?? a

/* Second Way */
if let b = b {
    a = b
}
```

In this context, it seems like the first way is probably fine, but when variables get much longer names like `mapViewController.destinationCardTitle`, the first way can get pretty long. I also can't just assign the value of `a` to `nil` or an empty `String` because if it already contains a non-nil value and `b = nil`, I don't want to change the value of `a`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to basically do the following without writing `a` twice.

```
a = b ?? a
```

Comment: Whats wrong with writing a twice? You can just write your own operator

Comment: The length of variable names has no influence on the performance of the code at all ;-)

Comment: Right, I get that, but it'd be nice to reduce the length of my code. Otherwise, I'd just never use the Nil-Coalescing Operator to begin with haha.

Comment: I personally find the second way more readable and I think you should prioritise readability over length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can design your own infix operator:

```
infix operator ?=
func ?=<T>(lhs: inout T, rhs: T?) {
    lhs = rhs ?? lhs
}

var a = "a"
var b: String? = "b"

a ?= b

print(a)  // "b\n"
```

Comment: My comment to this (similar) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34710530/1187415 applies here as well.

Comment: I added something similar to my answer (but not generic) before seeing this answer. This is cleaner than what I showed.

Comment: @MartinR `a ?= nil` worked for me here. I will test it with computed property also

Comment: It works, but even `a? = nil` will  call the property observers willSet/didSet, (because `a` is passed to the operator and then written back), which might be unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

Since your concern is with long variable names, let's look at your possibilities with long variable names:

nil-coalescing:

```
aLongVariableName = bCrazyLongVariableName ?? aLongVariableName
```

if-let:

```
if let x = bCrazyLongVariableName {
    aLongVariableName = x
}
```

if-nil:

```
if bCrazyLongVariableName != nil {
    aLongVariableName = bCrazyLongVariableName
}
```

Of those three possible options, `if let` is the shortest amount of code since each long variable name is only shown once. But you have the overhead of `if let x =` and the curly braces. So you need to have variable names that are long enough to counter that extra syntax.

Personally, readability is more important than length. And copy and paste means far less typing. For this reason, using `??` is the much better solution. Its intent is clearer.

You asked about a way to avoid the 2nd `a` using `??`. You can't. There is no other syntax that provides the real shortcut you are looking for.

You could write a function that takes `a` as an `inout` parameter and `b` as a normal parameter.

```
func x(_ a: inout String?, _ b: String?) {
    if b != nil {
        a = b
    }
}

var a = String?
var b = String?

x(&a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking *both* readability and length of code into consideration when providing a solid answer.

Comment: See my update that includes one possible solution.

Comment: I think the `inout` is probably my best bet here. I might just make a custom operator to do this..

Comment: Leo's answer shows a better solution for a general custom operator than what I show here.

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote (don't worry, I don't take revenge). I'm honestly curious why this answer is considered un-useful to someone.

Answer (score -3):

It sure is interesting - and this is when you have a golden opportunity to make the most out of Swift. Use the big hammer on this one:

```
var a: String?
var b: String?

func attempt_To_Set_A_New_Value_To_A(using b: Any?) -> String {
    if b != nil {
        guard b is String else {
            // OH no! It's not a string!!!
            return ""
        }
        // Just to make sure..
        if let bString = b as? String {
            return bString
        }
    }
    // WARNING - b is definitely nil!
    return ""
}

a = attempt_To_Set_A_New_Value_To_A(using b: b).isEmpty() ? a : attempt_To_Set_A_New_Value_To_A(using b: b)
```

If you want to have less fun, or you're simply having a bad day, I'd probably write it as such:

```
if b != nil { a = b }
```

Comment: What is the point of checking `b is String` before the optional cast `b as? String` ?

Comment: This makes very little sense. This function is many times more verbose at the call site, unnecessarily convoluted in its body, and doesn't even do what its name says.

Comment: It's definitely not a joke! ;)

Comment: Jokes go on forums. Here, we provide solutions to problems.